# iOS: Custom image UIBarButtonItem does not respond to touches

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uibarbuttonitem

I'm attempting to use images as buttons in my nav bar. The buttons display just fine, but they don't respond to touch events. Here's how I'm setting up the buttons:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up_24.png"]];

iv.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
UIBarButtonItem * logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:iv ];

logoutButton.target=self;
logoutButton.action=@selector(logoutButtonPressed);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you could try to use anonther initializer: `UIBarButtonItem * logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up_24.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(logoutButtonPressed)];`.

Comment: The problem is that this puts the image ON a button. That's not the look I want. I just want the image itself to be the button (with no border and whatnot). The code I posted gets the look right, it just won't respond to touches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember right, I had this problem with one of my past projects.  I believe it is an issue with the `UIBarButtonItem`.  The workaround would be...

```
UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithStyle:UIButtonStyleCustom];
imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,24,24);//Standard size of a UIBarButtonItem i think.
[imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up_24.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageButton];
```

//Add it to your bar or whatever here.

If you want the white glow like the regular buttons, you'll have to set

```
imageButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Comment: When I do this, my image doesn't show up at all. There's nothing there.

Comment: @JamesHarpe Oh yea, set a frame for the button

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, I think the issue is that you're setting the image object instead of a button object.

```
UIButton *navBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[navBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up_24.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem if that's your preference
UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightItemImage];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
```

Comment: As I mentioned on the other answer, when I do this, the image no longer shows up at all.

Comment: Same as above, I forgot to set the frame :).